# How to count input tags created by ng-repeat

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on an Angular app that has a large survey form. I am making a status bar that will indicate what percentage of the form has already been completed. The form contains 9 input fields that are written directly into the html, and about 50 that occur as a result of ng-repeating.

Part of my planned implementation is to count the number of input tags on the page. This way, if the users of the application change the survey form, the code will still handle the modifications. I wrote the following code in the survey's controller to store the number of input tags on the page:

```
$scope.numberOfInputFields = angular.element($document[0].querySelectorAll('input')).length;
```

My issue is that the code above returns the number of input fields that are directly written into the html, but does not count any of the input tags written by ng-repeat.

I believe that the code written above is being executed before ng-repeat renders, but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: use $last to find out the total-repeat-count of ng-repeat

Comment: @bigbaka who's printing the inputs sorry? which line of code? in ng-repeat its easy to check how many iterations are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]"  ng-value="$index" />

<input type="text" ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]" ng-value="$last" />
```

Just :

**$index**  number  iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

**$first**  boolean true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.

**$middle** boolean true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.

**$last**   boolean true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

**$even**   boolean true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).

**$odd**    boolean true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like at the time your counting statement is executed, the `ng-repeat` hasn't finished rendering yet.

You could try to defer the execution by a `$timeout` service:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.numberOfInputFields = angular.element($document[0].querySelectorAll('input')).length;
});
```

You may have to change the code that use the `$scope.numberOfInputFields` though.

However, it would be better if you can know the input count without counting on the DOM directly.

Comment: I agree with you that it will be better off not counting on the DOM directly, therefore I am going to make a count function in my controller that tallies the appropriate models. Thanks!